Bases loaded, no outs, can first base runner retreat after first base is tagged
Bases are loaded with no outs.  Ball hit into play. Runner on first starts to second and stops, first base is tagged while the first base runner is on first base and the batter had not made it to first. Ump calls out on batter and then Ball thrown to second where ump calls the first base runner out.
I believe that once the batter is called out with the tag at first, the force at second is no longer in affect and there should only be one out.

Your understanding is correct: a runner who starts on first base (who I'll call A) can attempt to return to first base if the batter/runner is made out (whether by tag or force out) before A is made out. In the scenario you present, all the runners who started on bases would be allowed to return to the base where they started the play.
A play that's practiced at (almost) all levels (I remember my little league team practicing it) is for the situation where there's a runner on first base and a ground ball is hit to the first baseman who fields it close to the base. The first baseman steps on the base to force out the batter/runner, then throws to the shortstop, who is covering second base, while yelling "Tag him" (or something similar). When successful, this is a way to make a double play while making only one throw instead of two. (Whether this is the best way to turn a double play would depend on the situation.) In such a situation, the runner who started on first base would be allowed to return to that base if they can.

While I believe this answer is correct, are you able to add a reference to the rulebook which supports it?
